# OpenCart 2.x Change default view to list-view

Tags: opencart2.x

I would like to permanently set the default view in OpenCart 2.1.0.2 to list-view instead of grid-view.  I do not want to give my visitors ability to switch to grid-view; hence I'd like to completely disable grid-view and keep only list-view.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using two methods for default list view.

**1st method**: replace following code (catalog/view/javascript/common.js)

```
if (localStorage.getItem('display') == 'list') {
    $('#list-view').trigger('click');
} else {
    $('#grid-view').trigger('click');
}
```

and using the following code in place

```
if (localStorage.getItem('display') == 'grid') {
    $('#grid-view').trigger('click');
} else {
    $('#list-view').trigger('click');
}
```

**2nd method**: If you don't want/like to permanently remove grid view then remove the code in (catalog/view/javascript/common.js) and make following code in common.js only

```
$('#grid-view').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your assistance.  I truly appreciate it!

Comment: Your welcome @ReenaOlaniyi . Please upvote if my answer is using your solution.